# Using Microsoft Report Builder: When there is no data, how can I add "No Data Available" message?

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, no-data

Can someone please help?

I am using Microsoft Report Builder, and would like to add a message stating "No Data Available" when no data is coming into the table.

Every time I use the "NoRowsMessage" in the properties or use the =CountRows() > 0 expression in one of the rows, it seems to not work.  I keep getting an empty row or empty two rows! And message does not show up at all.  Its like empty data is coming through which makes no sense.  And if I make sure there is real data comes through it looks fine.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image]
[image]

Updated Info:

```
declare @MeetingSessionID varchar(500)
set @MeetingSessionID = '160165815460010151522-101523-4111510-14142220'

select distinct vl.originalChatSessionID
      ,vl.applicationUserID
      ,vl.pharmaID
      ,vl.UserName
      --,isnull(ph.FirstName,'') as 'First Name'
      --,isnull(ph.MiddleName,'') as 'Middle Name'
      --,isnull(ph.LastName,'') as 'Last Name'
      --,phm.CompanyName
      ,isnull(dr.Title,'') as 'Title'
      ,isnull(dr.FirstName,'') as 'First Name'
      ,isnull(dr.MiddleName, '') as 'Middle Name'
      ,isnull(dr.LastName, '') as 'Last Name'
      ,isnull(dr.Name, '') as 'Name'
      , null as 'Specialty'
from iclickphrDxvideolog vl
    --inner join iclickphrDxpharmacy ph
    --  on ph.pharmacyProfileID = vl.applicationUserID
    --inner join iclickphrDxpharmacy_Main phm
    --  on phm.pharmacyID = ph.PharmacyID
    inner join iclickphrDxdoctor dr
        on dr.DoctorID = vl.pharmaID


where vl.originalChatSessionID = @MeetingSessionID
```

So for example i just want to see middle name in the table and thats it...but the column is empty...im getting two empty rows back...i want it to say "No Data Available". I know that the chatSessionID is what is bringing back two rows...but I need to have it there some how....to get data out of the other tables.

Comment: You probably need to share your report design and dataset query. Have you checked that zero rows are actually being returned by running your query in SSMS or similar?

Comment: I have this for the Video Viewed/Shared table because im just testing this right now.  Do not have an actual table made yet, waiting for dev team to add it.

`code
select distinct null as 'Video Name',
   null as 'Video Length'
     
from iclickphrDxvideolog vl

where vl.originalChatSessionID = @MeetingSessionID`

Comment: @AlanSchofield Ok thanks....i figured out that the NULL values are causing the rows to come back.  Is there a way i can make the NULL values act as NO DATA? So the empty row does not show up and can have the message be "No Data Available"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the situation regarding the lack of an actual table but you can mock up some data in your dataset query and use that.

A simple version might look something like (change datatypes to suit your real data)

```
DECLARE @iclickphrDxvideolog TABLE([Video Name] Varchar(100), [Video length] int, originalCharSessionID varchar(500), applicationUserID int, pharmaID int, UserName varchar(256))
INSERT INTO @iclickphrDxvideolog VALUES
('My first Video', 10, '160165815460010151522-101523-4111510-14142220', 1234, 1, 'Bob'),
('My second Video', 20, '160165815460010151522-101523-4111510-14142220', 3456, 1, 'Dave')

declare @MeetingSessionID varchar(500)
set @MeetingSessionID = '160165815460010151522-101523-4111510-14142220'

select distinct vl.originalChatSessionID
      ,vl.applicationUserID
      ,vl.pharmaID
      ,vl.UserName
      ,isnull(dr.Title,'') as 'Title'
      ,isnull(dr.FirstName,'') as 'First Name'
      ,isnull(dr.MiddleName, '') as 'Middle Name'
      ,isnull(dr.LastName, '') as 'Last Name'
      ,isnull(dr.Name, '') as 'Name'
      , null as 'Specialty'
from @iclickphrDxvideolog vl -- <= swapped out for table variable for testing
    inner join iclickphrDxdoctor dr
        on dr.DoctorID = vl.pharmaID
where vl.originalChatSessionID = @MeetingSessionID
```

If you test with a session id other than '160165815460010151522-101523-4111510-14142220', you should get 0 rows returned.

Comment: Thanks....that was a brain fart moment on how the data was coming out. too much work and not enough clarity.  But yes that makes sense and helped.  Just needed to change the session id.